# how to convert delimited column to different rows in IMPALA Query

Tags: hive, impala

The value of column scores are delimited by comma. Each userid has at least a score and there is no upper limit for the number of scores of each userid.

```
+--------+---------+
| userid | scores  |
+--------+---------+    
| u1     | C,B,A   | 
| u2     | A       |
| u3     | A,C     |
+--------+---------+
```

I want to get the result by 'select ...' sql

```
+--------+---------+
| userid | score   |
+--------+---------+
| u1     | C       |
| u1     | B       |
| u1     | A       |
| u2     | A       |
| u3     | A       |
| u3     | C       |
+--------+---------+
```

In hive, lateral `view explode(split(score,','))` may realize the requirement,

```
select userid, score from my_table lateral view explode(split(scores,',')) scores as score;
```

However impala does not support explode.

Is there an alternative way to realize it in impala?

Comment: I guess, you need to use hive. Impala wont work for this type of requirement(or i dont knwo).

Comment: I agree I found a way to do it in the hive but unfortunately, I want this to be done in IMPALA itself so I am trying to find a workaround for this. Any help would be appreciated.